# How to assign shortcut key to builtin style in MS Word 2010 using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, add-in

I have written code for Application level MS Word Addin according to my own requirement for built in headings now i want to assign shortcut key to them. Following is the code. While using word this can be achieved by clicking on a style i.e Heading 1-> modify->shortcut key

```
With oDoc.Styles(word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1)
.Font.Bold = False
.Font.Size = 12
.Font.Name = "Arial"
.Font.Spacing = 16
.NameLocal = "Heading1"
.BaseStyle = "Normal"
.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6
.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = 1
With .ParagraphFormat.TabStops
.Add(Position:=oWord.CentimetersToPoints(2),    Alignment:=word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdCenter)
End With
.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = True
.LinkToListTemplate(oTemplate1)
End With
```

Please guide how assign shortcut keys using code. 
also how to set property 
Aligned at: 0 cm
Indent at:0cm

Answer (score 0):

You can assign shortcut keys using `KeyBindings`, for example:

```
KeyBindings.Add wdKeyCategoryStyle, "Heading 1", BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeyAlt, wdKeyH)
```

would bind `Heading 1` to the `Ctrl-Alt-H` key combination.

Comment: still cant find  Aligned at: 0 cm Indent at:0cm property

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by Aligned and Indent. There is `ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent` and `ParagraphFormat.Alignment`